# Flutter Template Is not displaying debug

Tags: api, flutter, redux, postman, dio

flutter buddy press app which link my flutter app and my wordpress app is build on redux it makes request using dio like below to list an activity

```
static getAllActivityList(Map<String, dynamic> paramsMap) async {
    String requestUrl =
        "${getConfigHost()}/wp-json/buddyboss/v1/get_all_activity";
    Dio dio = new Dio();

    try {
      Response response = await dio.get(requestUrl,
          queryParameters: paramsMap,
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Authorization":
                makeAuthorizationHeader('GET', requestUrl, paramsMap)
          }));
      Activities listActivitity = Activities.fromJson(response.data);
      print("Hmmm");

      return listActivitity;
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      handleDioError(error);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The response in android is No data found the app uses auth1 for security but cant even debug on the app it didn't print any data or error or success i have tried logging library and other print but nothing shows. The response on post man works fine using authorization.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter clean
```

Run this in the terminal then try again , it will work

Comment: Started Debugging, then once up and running -> opened Dart DevTools but always get "Dart DevTools requires an active debug session.".

Comment: Direcway to Achieve it is to Update the VS Code . hope it will help you .